# First-order logic and second-order logic confusion

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory

> First-order logic uses only variables that range over individuals (elements of the domain of discourse); second-order logic has these variables as well as additional variables that range over sets of individuals. For example, the second-order sentence $\forall P\,\forall x (x \in P \lor x \notin P)$ says that for every set $P$ of individuals and every individual $x$, either $x$ is in $P$ or it is not (this is the principle of bivalence). ("Second-order logic", Wikipedia)

And

> In the formal language of set theory, the axiom schema is:
>   $\forall w_1,\ldots,w_n \, \forall A \, \exists B \, \forall x \, ( x \in B \Leftrightarrow [ x \in A \land \phi(x, w_1, \ldots, w_n, A) ] )$

Comparing and contrasting these two, I find that in the latter case, set $A$ can be considered as set of individuals that was quanitifed by universal quantifier. So, how is this different from second-order logic (in the first case, I would be referring to set $P$.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually we say that first-order quantification is to quantify over elements of the universe, while second-order allows quantification over subsets. However we can only think of second-order quantification as quantifiers over *predicates* and *relations* instead.

Why would we want to do that? Well, it removes the ambiguity about "sets" when it comes to *set theory* in which elements of the universe are subsets of the universe.

What does that mean? It means that second-order quantifications in ZFC are quantifiers over *classes* and not over sets. This is what makes ZFC a suitable foundation for mathematics, as it turns high-order logic into first-order logic, and first-order logic is good.

---

**To read more:**

1. [First-order logic advantage over second-order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/141759/622)
2. [advantage of first-order logic over second-order logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143438/622)
3. [First-Order Logic vs. Second-Order Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23799/622)

Comment: So you mean that even in first-order logic, we can allow first-order logic to quantify over sets of individuals - set $A$ in the quoted axiom of specification (when the thing quantified is not a non-set class)?

Comment: @user32751: The elements of the universe of ZFC are themselves subsets of the universe. Quantifying over these sets is first-order.

Comment: Just to be sure I'm understanding this, would the following then amount to such a 2nd order statement: $\exists g, \forall f . g(f) => \forall x,y  . f(x)=f(y)$ ?

Comment: @Motorhead: I don't know what you mean by any of that.