# ZFC set theory,first order theory

Tags: logic, set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Gödel's Completeness and Incompleteness Theorems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14709/what-is-the-difference-between-godels-completeness-and-incompleteness-theorems)
>   [what is the relationship between ZFC and first-order logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108415/what-is-the-relationship-between-zfc-and-first-order-logic)

I am a bit confused by a few things that I have read recently.

I have read that ZFC is a first order theory and that any part of mathematics can be expressed in ZFC. Now I know that first order logic is complete, however this would seem to contradict the incompleteness theorems (with I have a basic understanding of). I was wondering where I have gone wrong?

Thanks very much for any help (sorry for the silly question)

Comment: Re-read the incompleteness theorems ;)

Comment: Long story short: "complete" has at least two meanings.

Comment: First order logic is a complete theory (I think). But ZFC consists of first order logic plus the relation $\epsilon$ and the axioms of set theory and is incomplete.

Comment: Proof once again the Gödel was the greatest logician ever: not only did he prove an amazing theorem in his dissertation, but about two years later he proved its negation!

Comment: @AndréNicolas I slap my forehead and stad corrected.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14709/what-is-the-difference-between-godels-completeness-and-incompleteness-theorems/14710#14710

Answer (score 10):

"Complete" means *two different things* for a logic (such as first-order-logic) versus for a theory in that logic.

A **logic** is complete iff: Every sentence that has no counterexample-model can be proved.

A **theory** is complete iff: Every sentence that has no proof-of-its-negation can be proved.

First-order logic is complete in the first sense. ZFC is (assuming it is consistent) incomplete in the second sense -- that is, there are sentences that ZFC neither proves nor disproves. That's completely compatible with the logic being complete; it just means that for each such sentence there are models of ZFC where it is true, and other models where it is false.

Answer (score 5):

As in the comments is said, the word 'complete' has 2 different meanings.

That the first order logic is *complete*, is meant that it is complete w.r.t the corresponding first order *models*, that is: a formula is valid in all models iff it has a proof (a deduction consisting of finitely many formulas, using some specific deduction rules, like *modus ponens*..)

That ZFC is *incomplete*, is meant it is incomplete as an *axiom system*: there is a formula $\phi$ such that neither $\phi$ nor $\lnot\phi$ is not provable from ZFC. (And, in fact, it will be still incomplete if adding any more axioms).